# Bringing header in front through css

Tags: wordpress, html, css

Looking for header to display in front. This a sample image.
We have transparent background. 
I am trying to send a div behind transparent header image and place a text below that div(test) which is test test.Tried adjusting z index but didn't work and can be seen here.i tried to resize div to small but it doesn't center and displaces in mobile view.kindly overlook scrolling

http://jaipur.onlinewebshop.net/sample-page/

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
   var i;
   var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
   for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none"; 
   }
   slideIndex++;
   if (slideIndex > x.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
   x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
   setTimeout(carousel, 2000); 
}
```

```css
.mySlides {display:none;}
```

```html
<!--placed in head section-->
<div class="w3-content" id="klo1" style="max-width: 100%; text-align: center; background-color: #d9eaf2;color: #a00a9b; font-size: 29px; font-weight: bolder;font-family: 'BioRhyme', cursive;">
   <div class="mySlides w3-animate-top w3-xlarge w3-white w3-card-4">
       <p id="aaaa">test&nbsp;-&nbsp;test1 !!!</p>
   </div>
   <div class="mySlides w3-animate-top w3-xlarge w3-white w3-card-4">
       <p id="aaaa">test&nbsp;-&nbsp;test2 !!!</p>
   </div>
   <div class="mySlides w3-animate-top w3-xlarge w3-white w3-card-4">
       <p id="aaaa">test&nbsp;-&nbsp;test3 !!!</p>
   </div>
   <div class="mySlides w3-animate-top w3-xlarge w3-white w3-card-4">
       <p id="aaaa">test&nbsp;-&nbsp; test4 !!!</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

header image here:

[image]

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/demo doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: ok...will image attached will work.thanks

Comment: No...images aren't really much use here.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is the problem you are facing and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i am trying to get header in front

Answer (score 0):

This codepen should get you started: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wQLdEQ

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="w3-content" id="klo1">
 <div class="mySlides w3-animate-top w3-xlarge w3-white w3-card-4">
     <p id="aaaa">test&nbsp;-&nbsp;test1 !!!</p>
 </div>
 <div class="mySlides w3-animate-top w3-xlarge w3-white w3-card-4">
     <p id="aaaa">test&nbsp;-&nbsp;test2 !!!</p>
 </div>
 <div class="mySlides w3-animate-top w3-xlarge w3-white w3-card-4">
     <p id="aaaa">test&nbsp;-&nbsp;test3 !!!</p>
 </div>
 <div class="mySlides w3-animate-top w3-xlarge w3-white w3-card-4">
     <p id="aaaa">test&nbsp;-&nbsp; test4 !!!</p>
 </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.here i am trying to get header in front